# Tooltip / Popper.js - Resize after adding tooltip title dynamically

Tags: material-ui

I'm using Material-UI's `<Tooltip />` component to show dynamically fetched data. I trigger the AJAX call to fetch the data in the `onOpen` callback. Initially I'm showing a loading spinner but I replace that with the data fetched.

My problem is that the tooltip grows downwards with the new content, such that it goes under my cursor which makes the tooltip think I hovered it again, triggering another fetch for data.

Example how I'm using it:

```
<Tooltip
    title={
        users ? (
            <Grid container direction="column" spacing={8}>
                {users.map(user => (
                    <Grid item key={user}>
                        {user}
                    </Grid>
                ))}
            </Grid>
        ) : <Loading />
    }
>
    <span>hover me</span>
</Tooltip>
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/yq5j9qky7v

Looking at the Popper.js implementation, they have a method called `scheduleUpdate` to trigger redraw of the tooltip (adjust position and size) https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js/blob/master/docs/_includes/popper-documentation.md#popperscheduleupdate

My question is, is it possible to tap into that using only the Material-UI Tooltip component wrapper?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue, fixed it by calling after i updated the contents of the Popper:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize") )
```

Answer (score 0):

i packed the tooltip component (and its childre) in its own component and then used `useEffect` to update some `useState` variable and set the title to the `useState` variable.
This way only changes in `value` trigger the remote API query.

looks a bit like:

```js
const MyInput = (props) => {
  const [icdInfo, setIcdInfo] = useState({code: '', text: ''});
  const {id, value, placement, ...rest} = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDescription = async (code) => {
        return await myApi.get(`${apiUrl}/${code}`);
    };
    fetchDescription(value)
        .then((r) => {
          setIcdInfo({code: icd_code, text: r.data.text || 'Unknown'});
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          setIcdInfo({code: '', text: 'Error'});
        });
    return () => {};
  }, [value, icdInfo]);
  return (
    <Tooltip title={icdInfo.text} >
      <Child {...rest} />
    </Tooltip>
  );
};
```